# Enable view after call a custom progress SWIFT3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

im working with swift3 to show progress when the app update date on service rest.

To call progress:

```
var alert :UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: titulo, message: mensaje, preferredStyle: .alert)
      spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)
        spinner.center = CGPoint(x: 130.5, y: 130.5)
        spinner.color = UIColor.black
        spinner.startAnimating()
               alert.view.addSubview(spinner)
        self.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Show this

[image]

When , finish app execute:

```
session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
            print("Entered the completionHandler")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
             spinner.stopAnimating()
                 spinner.removeFromSuperview()
            alert.view.removeFromSuperview()

            }
............
```

But app don't recover the main view:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dismiss your alert instead of removing alert view

In your case your alert view was removed but presented

change `alert.view.removeFromSuperview()`

to `alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`

Comment: Thanks so much , perfect solution